# Remove \ from String

Tags: string, swift

I can not remove `\` from a query string in Swift. I am using multiple option but it didn't work so please help me.

The string is :

> "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO List VALUES(NULL,\'RS\',\'PRODUCTI
>   FO\',\'AX[Demo]\',\'abc\',\'All\',\'Sk\')"

I am using below solution

1)

```
let trimmedString = query.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
            NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
        )
```

2) `var query1: String = query.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)`

3)

```
let toArray = query.componentsSeparatedByString("\\")
        let backToString = toArray.joinWithSeparator("")
```

also when print query it perfect but when print on debug time it contain .

Comment: post code on how you're currently trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Update your question (don't post it in comments) with your relevant code.

Comment: What do you use the query string for?

Comment: `I am using multiple option but it didn't work` Which ones? Please [edit] your question and show what you've already tried and where you're stuck. Thank you.

Comment: Is this the result you need? `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO List VALUES(NULL,'RS','PRODUCTI FO','AX[Demo]','abc','All','Sk')` If not, what should be different?

Comment: Please do not modify a question in the way it becomes a different subject. Ask a new question. I reverted the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Before the solution your problem, put this code in your Swift Playground.

```
var str = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO List VALUES(NULL,\'RS\',\'PRODUCTI FO\',\'AX[Demo]\',\'abc\',\'All\',\'Sk\')"

var ary = [Character]()
for itm in str.characters{
  ary.append(itm)
}
print(ary)
```

If you carefully check the `ary` then you will see [image]

That means your string consist of `\'` not `\`. Now remove `\'`

```
let resultStr = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\'", withString: "")
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Md.Muzahidul IsIam, yes you are right , now it works.

Comment: it remove /' but query is in wrong formate ,it give me syntax error

Comment: @EricD. i want to remove only / not /' please see my question.